# Common parser error - could not load type...runs fine in localhost but throws error when published on server

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis

I'm getting the common parser error below whenever I try to run my application off of a web server...the application runs fine in localhost and when I publish it to IIS on my local machine and host it there. Any ideas what the issue could be?

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service        this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.edtk'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="edtk.aspx.vb" Inherits="_3rd_party_data_reporting_tool.edtk" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /gpo/edtk.aspx    Line: 1

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082
```

Comment: Did you publish the `edtk.aspx.vb` file to the server?

Comment: I don't see it in the destination folder on the server although it's not showing in the destination folder that I'm using to run it off of on my local machine using IIS either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was removing the comments in the web.config file...the reason the application ran fine on my localhost IIS and not on the server IIS was that the IIS versions were different and the version on the server's doesn't like comments in web.config.